# Access index of a list in Flutter/Dart

Tags: flutter, dart

I would like to access an index of a string (e.g. 'Hello') and print it to the app (e.g. letter 'o'). **This string has to be the input of the user.**
This can be easily done using Python but I have to use Flutter/Dart in order to do it (mobile development).

Here is just an example of how this would be solve using Python:

```
my_word = input("Insert your word here: ")

print(my_word[4])
```

Comment: Take a look at [Retrieve the value of a text field](https://flutter.dev/docs/cookbook/forms/retrieve-input) and the [Text widget](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/Text-class.html).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Use [`TextField`](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/TextField-class.html) to retrieve user's input:

> A text field lets the user enter text, either with hardware keyboard
> or with an onscreen keyboard.

2. Use [`Text`](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/Text-class.html) to display the string that you retrieve:

> The Text widget displays a string of text with single style.

3. Use the [`[]` (index)](https://api.dart.dev/stable/2.13.4/dart-core/String-class.html) operator to get the character at the index you specify:

```dart
final str = "Hello World";

print(str[4]); // Prints o
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try split the string's letters in an array first.

`my_word.split('')[4]`

Answer (score 0):

[image: dartPad]

```
main() {
  String val = "hello";
  print(val[4]);
}
```